# webview_zygote32: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_99009: Permission denied android

Tags: android

I got an error when loading a layout with WebView element.  "Chrome has stopped" popped up.
in logcat:

"webview_zygote32: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_99009: Permission denied android" when doing

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Thanks in advance for shedding light on the issue.

1. I added 
   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
   into AndroidManifested.xml
2. It works fine in a new project on the same AVD emuluator.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by building a new project and moving all modules to the new project one by one.